# Set all class member variables in one line of code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class with several member variables which I initialize upon construction:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4
        self.var5 = var5
        self.var6 = var6
        self.var7 = var7
        self.var8 = var8
```

Is there any pythonic way to do this in a single line of code?

I tried using `eval`, but that didn't work of course:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8):
        for var in 'var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8'.split(','):
            eval('self.'+var+'='+var)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could easily use `**kwargs` and `setattr`…?!

Comment: @deceze: Thanks. Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: Hint: hands off from **evil** eval...

Comment: @bub: Don't need that hint, I've already said "doesn't work of course".

Comment: @goodvibration every programmer needs that hint ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 1

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8):
        self.__dict__.update(locals())
        del self.self
        y = 3

c = MyClass(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
for var in 'var1 var2 var3 x y self'.split():
    print var, ':', getattr(c, var, 'not present')
```

Output:

```
var1 : 2
var2 : 3
var3 : 4
x : not present
y : not present
self : not present
```

This is a hack. Some drawbacks:

1. If you define `MyClass` inside a scope that isn't the top level (i.e. inside a function), or if `self.__dict__.update(locals())` isn't the first line in `__init__`, you may get unwanted variables.
2. This or any other magical solution messes up inference for linters (e.g. PyCharm).
3. This bypasses special attribute setting hooks such as properties or `__setattr__`. In such situations, you can use a solution more like deceze's:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, prop):
        for k, v in locals().items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
        del self.self

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, val):
        self._prop = val

c = MyClass(2, 3)
print c.var1, c.prop, c._prop  # 2 3 3
```

Comment: Well, "define `MyClass` inside a scope that isn't the top level" - no worries there. This solution is the cleanest, and I didn't have to apply any changes in my code except for the `__init__` method itself. Thank you!!!

Comment: Directly updating `self.__dict__` will bypass any computed attribute (`property` or else). Also, `locals()` will return __all__ local variables, wherever they are defined in the function, and including `self` (which will make the instance keeping a reference on itself, making garbage collection harder). IOW this is a very brittle solution, at best.

Comment: @goodvibration this is definitly NOT the cleanest solution, cf my above comment. The cleanest solution is the one you're already using: explicitely settings the attributes. Might be a bit boring to type but it will save you lot of troubles in the long run.

Comment: Except for the fact that it adds an "extra" member: `'self': <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x03475918>`. How can I remove this from the dictionary returned by `local()`?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers you raised some good points, I have addressed them. Note that "locals() will return all local variables, wherever they are defined in the function" is incorrect.

Comment: @AlexHall indeed `locals()` will not collect variables defined after the call, I must have borked my test somehow ;)

Comment: Instead of `del self.self`, you could just filter it out in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 6):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, k, v)
```

The disadvantage is that you can now pass anything and everything as properties and it's badly documented.

Comment: Note that you will also have to pass everything as kwargs instead of positionally, but with 8 different arguments you should already be doing that for your own sanity.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I now create a `MyClass` instance??? I get `__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (9 given)`.

Comment: @goodvibration you have to name the arguments, as in `MyClass(var1=1, var2=2, ...)`.